# Unsplash API does not search for the correct query

Tags: reactjs, api

I am trying to render two images from from Unsplash with the developer API.
When I click a button, it gets the two first images from the data, but I can't get it to search for a specific query.

It does not matter what query I put in, it just find the same two images again and again.

My function for the api call:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  const getImage = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `https://api.unsplash.com/photos/?client_id=${API_KEY_IMAGES}&query=dog`
    );
    const data = await res.data;
    const firstTwoImages = [data[0], data[1]];
    setImages(firstTwoImages);
  };
```

With this call I want images of dogs as the query is query=dog, but no matter what I put in the query, it always render two images which has nothing to do with the query string.

Related code:

A component called Images:

```
export const Images = ({ images }) => {
  console.log(images);
  return images.map((image) => <Image key={image.id} image={image} />);
};
```

A component called Image:

```
export const Image = ({ image }) => {
  return (
    <div className="photo">
      <img src={image.urls.thumb} alt="Unsplash images" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

And the render:  *(note: weatherValue is for another component)*.

```
<button className="imageBtn" onClick={getImage}>
  Try finding an image of {weatherValue.name}
</button>
<div className="photos">{<Images images={images} />}</div>
```

Here is the unsplash documentation that I have tried to follow:
https://unsplash.com/documentation#search-photos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem.
The url I fetched was wrong.

The correct url is supposed to be:

```
const url = `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos/?query=${city}&client_id=${API_KEY_IMAGES}`;
```